# Customize parts of the page

Tags: pagination

I have a question about template making:

A page that consists of three parts:

Text above,

Middle text

Bottom text.

There are 4 buttons with the name of text below 1, text below 2, text below 3, text below 4 at the bottom of this page.

How can I change the third part (lower text) by clicking on the button with the name of the lower text 2, so that this change is applied only to the lower text and the upper text and the middle text do not change?

Then, by clicking on the button with the name of the text below 3, I will continue this process and each time you click on these 4 buttons, only the text below will change.

I want to use this capability in MediaWiki.

Thank you for your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry again the rules to answer with a request for clarification, but I cannot comment to the question, only answer it. I would be able to help if I know a bit more.

It all depends what you want to show when clicking on the buttons?
Are you showing hidden texts? Or do you need a page from the wiki to be shown ?
A bit more info would be helpful.